# How to periodically copy from one database to another inside a single RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Can someone point me to the correct direction or terminology? I've been searching about it but I can't find any relevant info. *It may be the keywords or terms I'm using.*

I have a one RDS instance with two MySQL databases. I'd like to copy data from **some tables** in Database A to Database B, a couple of times a day.

Is this possible? If it is, can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: Create a scheduled task/cron job to do this?

Comment: You can try [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) for accessing the databases in RDS. Give the MySQL host name,port,username and password to connect. Databases can also be [synced](http://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/292-starting-database-synchronization) with option for scheduling the sync.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AWS Lambda Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-scheduled-events.html) to [access your RDS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809890/can-aws-lambda-connect-to-rds-mysql-database-and-update-the-database) and copy the tables from your Database A to Database B.